# Text disappears when javascript is activated

Tags: javascript, html

I am practicing JavaScript by following examples and have come across a problem.

I want "This text does not show" to appear with a randomly selected array item. Unfortunately, only the randomly selected array item appears, and the "This text does not show" won't appear when I open it in the browser. What would be a solution this beginner's problem?

Thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

This text does not show

</body>

<script>
var myArray = [
  "Apple",
  "Bananas",
  "Pears"
];

var randomItem = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];

document.body.innerHTML = randomItem;
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid: you’re lacking a `<head>` section and your `<script>` is outside your `<body>`. You assign something to `document.body.innerHTML`. Why do you expect the old value of `document.body.innerHTML` to still show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to append the randomly selected item to the `innerHTML`.  Like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

This text does not show

</body>

<script>
var myArray = [
  "Apple",
  "Bananas",
  "Pears"
];

var randomItem = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];

document.body.innerHTML += randomItem;
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were replacing the document's inner html, rather than appending to it:

```js
var myArray = [
  "Apple",
  "Bananas",
  "Pears"
];

var randomItem = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];

document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + randomItem;
```

```html
This text does not show
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `document.body.innerHTML = randomItem` **to**:

`document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + randomItem`

This `document.body.innerHTML = randomItem` replace the whole `body` for the random item.

On the other hand, this `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + randomItem` replaces the whole `body` for its previous values *plus* the random item.

```js
var myArray = [
  "Apple",
  "Bananas",
  "Pears"
];

var randomItem = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + randomItem;
```

```html
This text does not show
```

Answer (score 1):

YOu have to  concatenate the string

```
document.body.innerHTML += randomItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the syntactical errors in the formatting of your HTML, a reason why you are only seeing the `randomItem` instead of the "This text does not show" is because you are overwriting the body's content with innerHTML.

Consider appending the `randomItem` as a DOM element as a child using the `appendChild()` method.